# I want to retrieve a set of rows that match or intersect two columns in ArcGIS survey123 connect

Tags: arcgis-survey123-connect

In my survey form, I have a Test.csv table stored in media containing the following columns (fromGroup, fromType, toGroup, viaFeature, viaGroup, viaType).

I would like a form where I will select the values ​​for (fromGroup, fromType) and (toGroup, toType) and then return the values ​​(viaFeature, viaGroup, viaType) of this intersection.

1. I've come close using an XLSForm. I was able to fill in the input values, but am having trouble pulling the data from their intersection.

The example of the XLSForm :

- survey:
  type: select_one fromGroupOption
  name: fromGroupOption
  label: From Group
  appearance: autocomplete search('Test', 'fromGroup')

  ```
    type: select_one fromTypeOption
    name: fromTypeOption
    label: From Type
    appearance: autocomplete search('Test', 'fromType')
    relevant: selected(${fromGroupOption})

    type: select_one toGroupOption
    name: toGroupOption
    label: To Group
    appearance: autocomplete search('Test', 'toGroup')

    type: select_one toTypeOption
    name: toTypeOption
    label: To Type
    appearance: autocomplete search('Test', 'toType')
    relevant: selected(${toGroupOption})

   calculate:
   name: viaFeature
   calculation: "pulldata('Test.csv', 'viaFeature', 'fromGroup=' || ${fromGroupOption} || ' and fromType=' || ${fromTypeOption} || ' and toGroup=' || ${toGroupOption} || ' and toType=' || ${toTypeOption})"

    calculate:
    name: viaGroup
    label: Via Group
    calculation: "pulldata('Test.csv', 'viaGroup', 'fromGroup=' || ${fromGroupOption} || ' and fromType=' || ${fromTypeOption} || ' and toGroup=' || ${toGroupOption} || ' and toType=' || ${toTypeOption})"

   calculate:
   name: viaType
   label: Via Type
   calculation: "pulldata('Test.csv', 'viaType', 'fromGroup=' || ${fromGroupOption} || ' and fromType=' || ${fromTypeOption} || ' and toGroup=' || ${toGroupOption} || ' and toType=' || ${toTypeOption})"
  ```
- choices:
  list_name: fromGroupOption
  name: fromGroup
  label: From Group

  ```
    list_name: fromTypeOption
    name: fromType
    label: From Type

    list_name: toGroupOption
    name: toGroup
    label: To Group

    list_name: toTypeOption
    name: toType
    label: To Type
  ```

2. XLSform was not give the results I'm expecting, I tried using JavaScript code, but the code is give me the error (line: 1, col:8 expected token ',')

The example of the JavaScript code:

```
async function getInterception() {
  const fromGroup = document.querySelector('select[name="fromGroupOption"]').value;
  const fromType = document.querySelector('select[name="fromTypeOption"]').value;
  const toGroup = document.querySelector('select[name="toGroupOption"]').value;
  const toType = document.querySelector('select[name="toTypeOption"]').value;

  const response = await fetch('media/Test.csv');
  const csvData = await response.text();
  
  const rows = csvData.split('\n');
  const headers = rows[0].split(',');

  const viaFeatureIndex = headers.indexOf('viaFeature');
  const viaGroupIndex = headers.indexOf('viaGroup');
  const viaTypeIndex = headers.indexOf('viaType');

  const interception = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    const row = rows[i].split(',');
    const rowFromGroup = row[0];
    const rowFromType = row[1];
    const rowToGroup = row[2];
    const rowToType = row[3];
    const viaFeature = row[viaFeatureIndex];
    const viaGroup = row[viaGroupIndex];
    const viaType = row[viaTypeIndex];

    if (rowFromGroup === fromGroup && rowFromType === fromType && rowToGroup === toGroup && rowToType === toType) {
      interception.push({ viaFeature, viaGroup, viaType });
    }
  }

  return interception;
}
```

I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide guidance on how to achieve this using wheter XLSform or JavaScrip function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.